# Calling asyncio task

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have the code. Why is the task not called when exiting the asyncio main? What is the logic of calling tasks?

```py
async def func1():
    print('func1')
    ### task2 = asyncio.create_task(func2())
    return 'func1-result'

async def func2():
    print('func2')
    return 'func2-result'

async def main():
    print('main')
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(func1())
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(func2())
    return 'main-result'

res = asyncio.run(main())
```

I get in stdout:

```
main
func1
func2
```

But if i do:

```py
import asyncio

async def func1():
    print('func1')
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(func2())
    return 'func1-result'

async def func2():
    print('func2')
    return 'func2-result'

async def main():
    print('main')
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(func1())
    ### task2 = asyncio.create_task(func2())
    return 'main-result'

res = asyncio.run(main())
```

```
main
func1
```

Why, in the first case, task2 enters the event loop and executes, but in the second it does not?

Comment: Your program exits before task2 runs

Comment: And it exits before task1 runs in the first case

Comment: There is some overhead in exiting,  it is apparently sufficient to schedule the task1.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the event loop via `asyncio.run` or `loop.run_until_complete`, the loop gives any tasks that were scheduled before the completion of the coroutine one last chance to run (this is really a behavior of stopping the loop). In your first example, a task is schedule for each of `func1` and `func2` before `main` completes. In your second example, a task is scheduled for `func1` before `main` completes. But since `func1` won’t get to run until after `main` completes, the task for `func2` gets scheduled too late and never runs.

Answer (score 0):

```
import asyncio

async def func1():
    print('func1')
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(func2())
    return 'func1-result'

async def func2():
    print('func2')
    return 'func2-result'

async def main():
    print('main')
    task1 = await asyncio.create_task(func1())
    ### task2 = asyncio.create_task(func2())
    return 'main-result'

res = asyncio.run(main())
```

Does work, you should await te result of functions because you didn't the result is delivered after the functions are closed.And the await is necessary because the result of function 2 is not ready before task1 is closed, the await is to allow func2 to finish before closing funct1.

Comment: It's clear with await. But what is the difference between my two cases